# Brand new Samsung 32 GB USB flash drive destroyed trying to make a bootable Windows 11 installer using Rufus. Is it real or fake?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, windows-11, rufus

So this is almost identical situation to the post below.

[USB totally damaged after used with Rufus](https://superuser.com/questions/1533421/usb-totally-damaged-after-used-with-rufus)

Please have a look at that and do not ask me to try the suggestions given there as I have tried all of those and nothing has worked. The flash drive just shows no media. It is detected by windows explorer as well as diskpart etc but has no partition. It appears that the error occurred when Rufus was trying to convert MBR partition on the flash drive to GPT. I don't know if this was caused by the software or faulty flash drive. I don't know if it can be fixed by some software that can rebuild partition?

And yes, fortunately the seller has agreed to send me a replacement one so hopefully I will receive one that will not die on me as well but having said that even though I have used Rufus countless number of times in the past to create bootable drives, I will be using an external hard drive where ever possible from now on.

With regards to the flash drive prior to this failure, I used it probably around 10 to 15 times to move and or copy files on windows as well as mac and Linux and it was working perfectly fine and was very fast so it wasn't showing any faults or errors beforehand.

I got the following info with ChipGenius.

- **Description**: [F:]USB Mass Storage Device(ChipsBnk Flash Disk)
- **Device Type**:  Mass Storage Device
- **Protocal Version**: USB 2.00
- **Current Speed**: High Speed
- **Max Current**: 100mA
- **USB Device ID**: VID = 1E3D PID = 198A
- **Device Revision**: 0100
- **Manufacturer**: ChipsBnk
- **Product Model**: Flash Disk
- **Product Revision**: 5.00
- **Controller Vendor**: ChipsBank
- **Controller Part-Number**: CBM2199E - [2019-11-11]
- **Flash ID code**:      2CA40832A100 - Micron - 1CE/Single Channel [TLC] -> Total Capacity = 32GB

Tools on web: http://dl.mydigit.net/special/up/chipsbank.html

Possible Flash Part-Number

Unknown

Flash ID mapping table

[Channel 0] [Channel 1]

2CA40832A100

[image: As shown by windows explorer]

[image: As shown in diskpart]

[image: As shown in windows disk management]

[image: Fake Samsung USB]

[image]

https://web.archive.org/web/20201001185629/https://anthoncode.com/en/identify-original-and-fake-samsung-usb-flash-drive/

Comment: How sure are you that the usb disk was a good drive to begin with? Chinese manufacturers create disks that are 16 GB, do some magic on the firmware to make it appear as a 1TB drive etc, and as long as you don't format the drive, but only write to it, all seems fine until you go over the 16GB limit. In that case, it will start overwriting previously written data while the drive appears to work correctly. If you have such drive, then chances are any format action will indeed destroy the drive. And yes, there are famous-name knock-offs too. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: If the drive is as new as you say, return it under warrantee. A pendrive should not fail a simple rufus format action to create a windows install medium.

Comment: I guess you have tried to create again a partition with `diskpart` and also the disk manager, and since both have failed (if I have well understood), GParted. What has been displayed ? Which error messages ?

Comment: I formatted the drive before this and also converted it to GPT and then back to MBR using diskpart and all was fine so this certainly wasn't the first time it would have been used.

Comment: I get identical error messages as in the post I mentioned above.

Comment: Please edit your question to include screenshots of those errors

Comment: Apparently it may be possible to fix this USB flash drive by using the software "chipsbank cbm 2199e umptool v7200". I have only found some russian site but it only contains malware and not the actual application.

Comment: @resurepus - The package has a spelling mistake it has “mageet proof” instead of “magnet proof” a mistake that Samsung wouldn’t make but a fake Chinese supplier would make.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author has resolved their own issue

Comment: There is another spelling mistake: `ER` instead of `FR` for the French translation. Looks a bit sus... Anyway perhaps post your edit as an answer and accept it if it's fixed.

Comment: The item is definitely fake and I was able to get a full refund from the seller when I showed him the evidence as described in the link I have posted in my original post. He also let me keep the 2 flash drives so I now have 2 fake USB flash drives for free!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover files from an USB flash drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/89579/how-do-i-recover-files-from-an-usb-flash-drive)

Answer (score 1):

So I used a separate machine to download the chipsbank software from https://www.usbdev.ru/files/chipsbank/cbm2099umptool/ with the windows defender turned off and it turned out to be just perfect to reprogram the USB flash drive without causing any issues or infecting the system with any virus/ransomware etc. For some reason defender identifies all software from that site as malware. It took quite a long time (over an hour) but the USB is once again alive and working as it should.

Just to point out that this is indeed a fake device and I was able to get a full refund from the seller when I presented him with the evidence.

Comment: _"Just to point out that this is indeed a fake device"_ You should edit your question to make it explicit that the reason your USB was destroyed is because it was a fake device in the first place. This will help other people realize that their issue may not have anything to do with the application that was used to write to the device, but with having been sold a fake drive. Thanks.