# USB flash not working after PC turned off while formating

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, formatting

So I was using Rufus to put a copy of Windows 10 on a USB flash drive. The power suddenly cut and after the USB flash drive stopped working.

I tried some solutions but they fail, is the damage irreversible?

Additional details:

- Disk Management literally doesn't open at all like crashes but…
- If I load it then add the USB it says: Unallocated.
- `chkdsk` also doesn't work
- Trying to format just gives a “failed to format” error.
- I don't have any data stored on it *obviously*
  it does show up in explorer.
- When I click it, it says: “Instert Disk” (lol)
- And it shows like it is connecting and disconnecting in explorer

Is there any way for me to fix it?

**Note**: Even if it is a "duplicate" the solutions I got from them are of no help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only). Or [USB flash drive not working or is appearing as an empty disk drive, Disk Management reports "No Media" with 0 bytes size](https://superuser.com/questions/871850/usb-flash-drive-not-working-or-is-appearing-as-an-empty-disk-drive-disk-managem)

Comment: It’s a duplicate because the end message of a situation like this is basically the USB flash drive is dead. And there is really no way to revive it. If there is not useful data on the USB flash drive, consider yourself lucky. You just have a useless device.

Comment: Plus it's not the only duplicate, you should just look harder: https://superuser.com/q/1533421/705502