# What to do to get past a USB flash drive “No Media” error?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, diskpart, mmc

I have a laptop which reliably breaks USB flash drives. It's done it to three different known good USB flash drives, and once the USB flash drive is broken, it has a drive letter assigned, but I can't use MMC to reformat or repartition it.

MMC shows it has a drive letter, but formatting fails, telling me there is no media. When I run diskpart and select the USB flash drives (each of them in turn) and try running *clean*, I get

> Virtual Disk Service error:
> There is no media in the device.

[image]

The HP utility mentioned [previously in this question](https://superuser.com/q/871850/167207) also returns a no media error.

The Bootice utility mentioned in the aforementioned link is no longer available, and the Russian utility is rejected by Windows Defender as containing viruses.

Comment: Thank you for providing that dubious flash eater story. It was entertaining as you left out naming the flash drives models affected and did not ask a question. Do you know what "shouting" with regards to netiquette means?

Comment: I guess what you mean by "the HP utility" but I don't know what the "Russian utility" is. How about specifying the names of the utilities or at least naming the site you have downloaded them from?

Comment: Also note that one flash drives are bad, it is very rare for them to be repairable. I think what the others are referring to is that you're heavily assuming people will be very familiar with the details of that other question. While it is another question on this site, it should still not be necessary to follow that link to understand what you're trying to tell us. So EDIT your question to clearly list the tools you've tried and their outcome.

Comment: do other USB devices work in the port(s) that break flash drives?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [USB totally damaged after used with Rufus](https://superuser.com/questions/1533421/usb-totally-damaged-after-used-with-rufus)